# How do I plot a curve on top of a ggplotsurv Kaplan Meier

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, survival-analysis

I've plotted a Kaplan Meier using ggsurvplot on a survift object and I am trying to plot another curve on top. The line is a vector of mean survival times. My KM is estimated from IPD with 225 observations with a maximum survival time of 7.2 years and my mean survival times are estimated from a Bayesian analysis with samples drawn from the posterior survival function at 6 month intervals. The problem seems to be that the additional line I'm trying to plot from the mean survival times is not the same length is my IPD dataframe, aside from dividing the last survival time by number of observations in my IPD and resampling at these intervals from the posterior distribution I'm wondering if there is anyway around this?

My data looks like this,

```
## IPD data

   treatment      t event
2          1 5.5250     1
3          1 1.9493     1
4          1 4.9473     1
7          1 5.9466     0
11         1 1.5797     1
12         1 0.5038     1
.              .        .
.              .        . 
.              .        .

## mean survival times from the Bayesian analysis

1.0000000 0.9129731 0.8337045 0.7614860 0.6956758 0.6356917 .....
```

The code I'm trying,

```
f <- survfit(Surv(t, event)~1, data=treatment)
f1 <- ggsurvplot(f) 
f2 <- f1$plot + geom_line(aes(c(0:16), meansurv))
```

Doing this I get the following error,

```
<error/rlang_error>
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (225): x and y
```

Additional question, I'm not sure how produce a plot with only 1 legend, the following produces two, if I use legend="none", both are removed.

```
meansurv1 <- c(1.0000000, 0.9129731, 0.8337045, 0.7614860, 0.6956758, 0.6356917, 0.50, 0.43, 0.37)
meansurv2 <- c(1.0000000, 0.9324888, 0.8671987, 0.8042297, 0.7436717, 0.6856045, 0.6300962, 0.5772029, 0.5269681)
x<- c(0:8)
temp <- data.frame(x, meansurv1, meansurv2)

temp<- temp %>% 
  gather(key, value, -c(x))


f1 <- survfit(Surv(t, event)~1, data=control)
f1 <- ggsurvplot(f1, legend="right") 
f1 <- f1$plot +  geom_line(data = temp, aes(x=x, y=value, group=key, color=key));f1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the use of `geom_line`. Since you haven't specified the `data` argument inside `geom_line` it is `NULL`. In the help of `geom_line` it is stated that the data is inherited from the plot data if `data = NULL` inside `geom_line`.

You can specify the `data` argument inside `geom_line` to get rid of the problem.

Attached there is a reproducible example. I took the numbers given in your question, but I've adjusted the vector `meansurv` so that this vector has more entries than the number of rows of the data frame `treatment`.

First I have reproduced your error and then I've shown how one can do it right using the argument `data` of the function `geom_line()`

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: ggplot2
#> Lade nötiges Paket: ggpubr

# a preview of the data frame. 
treatment <- data.frame(
  treatment = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  t = c(5.525, 1.9493, 4.9473, 5.9466, 1.5797, 0.5038), 
  event = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
  )

# modified vector: 
meansurv <- c(1.0000000, 0.9129731, 0.8337045, 0.7614860, 0.6956758, 0.6356917, 0.50, 0.43, 0.37)

f <- survfit(Surv(t, event)~1, data=treatment)
f1 <- ggsurvplot(f); f1
```

[image]

```r
# data is not used in geom_line ->> raises error: 
f2 <- f1$plot + geom_line(aes(seq.int(meansurv) - 1, meansurv)); f2
#> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (7): x and y


# using argument data: 
f2 <- f1$plot + geom_line(data = data.frame(x = seq.int(meansurv) - 1, 
                                            y = meansurv), 
                          aes(x = x, y = y)); f2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to add several lines, do you know how to add a legend for multiple geom_lines and remove the legend for the KM?

Comment: I would put together all the data needed for the lines in one data frame and add a grouping variable. Then you just need one geom_line and you can use the color aesthetic. In general the legend should then appear but I could help you much better if you could provide a minimal example of what you've done so far.

Comment: I've added the code similar to what I use what causes me to get two legends when I just need the one.

Comment: add `+ guides(fill = "none")` behind your `geom_line` call.